# Spring boot 3 with queryDSL

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl

How i can to generate Q-classes using queryDSL with Spring Boot 3.0.

part of build.gradle:

```
plugins {
   id 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl' version '1.0.10'
}

configurations {
   querydsl.extendsFrom implementation, compileOnly, runtimeOnly, annotationProcessor
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
   implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa'

   annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt'

   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
   testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'

   runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

}

querydsl {
   jpa = true
   library = 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0'
   querydslSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main"
}

compileQuerydsl {
   options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

I try to create Q-classes by own hands, but it's doesn't work(

Comment: Can you elaborate how it doesn't work? Are you getting a specific exception? Can you share the code where you create Q classes?

Comment: I get some exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity.
Maybe in build.gradle i can overriding path from javax to jakarta?

Comment: related?: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3651

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recevied the same error upgrading to Spring Boot 3.

I followed the small hint from QueryDSL release notes:
http://querydsl.com/releases.html
https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2612

And I replaced in my build.gradle:

```
api 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa' -> api 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
```

and

```
annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jpa' -> annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
```

Comment: Hi @Jyrgen, thanks for the answer. Translate this to maven please

Comment: Something like this:

```<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>```

```<annotationProcessorPath>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</annotationProcessorPath>```

Comment: did you find a way to make it work with Springboot 3 and Maven build?

Answer (score 2):

To add more info for maven users based on @Jyrgen answer:

`Dependencies`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-sql-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```

where ${querydsl.version} = 5.0.0

`Plugins` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: A small clarification here, if you are using Spring Boot, then the framework already establishes the `querydsl.version` property compatible with their stack, there is no need to hardcode/override this in the project

Comment: @GerardoRoza Boot's dependency management does not include the classifier. If you add the classifier then you also need to re-specify the version.

Answer (score 2):

Library used to write SQL in (generated) object notation

Supports Jakarta namespace but…

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
   <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
   *<classifier>jakarta</classifier>*
</dependency>
```

Jakarta classifier uses Eclipse Transformer plugin to package a jar with jakarta.* package names
Also when including querydsl-apt as an annotation processor path for maven-compiler-plugin
Ditch the old **com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin**

Comment: Its work, I add in plugin the same content

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
          </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

For Gradle this configs worked fine for me

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '5.0.0', classifier: 'jakarta'
    annotationProcessor group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: '5.0.0', classifier: 'jakarta'
    annotationProcessor group: 'jakarta.persistence', name: 'jakarta.persistence-api', version: '3.1.0'
}
```

without configuring`jakarta.persistence-api` dependency as annotation processor I was getting error
`> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Entity`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem recently, but I solved it and now it works fine.
Here are the relevant parts of `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.20"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.20"
    // Important use this kapt
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.22" 
}
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta")
    // Important. It turns out that this is jpa. Change it to jakarta.
    // kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jpa")
    kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
}
```

The key points are two important places marked.
Here is the link: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3651

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-core:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-sql:5.0.0'
implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-sql-spring:5.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
```